# React useState variable not updating in function call happening after useEffect registers state change

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks

I'm making a React component that takes some time to finish loading.

Meanwhile, if the user attempts to invoke a function on it (e.g., testIfDoneLoading()), I aim to save that function call.
Once the component is ready, I can execute the saved function call as requested.

I am using `useState` to initialize a loading state variable with a default value of true. When the component is mounted, I update the loading state by invoking `setLoading(false),` setting it to `false.`

I've implemented a `useEffect` hook that monitors changes in the loading state. When `loading` transitions to `false,` I trigger the queued function if it is defined.

The issue is that when I call the queued function, despite being called from the `useEffect` where I verify `loading` has been set to false, `loading` is still set to true and queues up the function again instead of continuing. However, if I directly call the function (not via `queuedFunction`), it works fine, with `loading` being set to false.

[Here's the stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/stackblitz-starters-1fwbcf?description=React%20%20%20TypeScript%20starter%20project&file=src%2FApp.tsx&title=React%20Starter) and code below. Notice how the console says it is still loading despite the template showing loading is finished. If you uncomment the direct function call (`testIfDoneLoading()`) and comment out the queued function (`queuedFunction.current()`), it works as intended.

```
  const [loading, setLoading] = useState(true);
  const queuedFunction = useRef<(() => void) | undefined>(undefined);

  useEffect(() => {
    // try to call a function before loading is done
    testIfDoneLoading();

    // mock something taking time to load
    setTimeout(() => {
      // when done loading, set the loading state to false
      setLoading(false);
    }, 1000);
  }, []);

  useEffect(() => {
    // after loading is false, if we've got a queued function, call the queued function
    if (!loading && queuedFunction.current) {
      // testIfDoneLoading(); // if called directly, this works with the latest state update of `loading` to false
      queuedFunction.current(); // but if called from the queuedFunction, the state change is not registered, and `loading` is still true
      queuedFunction.current = undefined;
    }
  }, [loading]);

  function testIfDoneLoading() {
    //If a function is called during the loading process, save it to be called when loading is complete
    // ISSUE: this `loading` is coming back as `true` even after `loading` is set to `false` and this function is called from the `queuedFunction` that sits within the `useEffect` that relies on `loading` being false (and in the template `loading` is false)
    if (loading) {
      console.log('Still Loading');
      queuedFunction.current = () => testIfDoneLoading();
    } else {
      console.log('Done Loading!');
    }
  }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is because when you are calling `testIfDoneLoading()` in your useEffect it is a **closure**.

When you define the function `testIfDoneLoading` it remembers the variables that are in the parent function, it bundled with its lexical scope (loading in this case).

Then when you call the function `testIfDoneLoading()` you capture the variable **value** of loading at this time.

Example:

```js
function makeFunction() {
  let y = 20;
  return function() {
    console.log(y);  // Remembers y because of closure 
  }
}
const closureFunction = makeFunction();
closureFunction();  // prints 20
```

So when you do

```js
useEffect(() => {
    // try to call a function before loading done
    testIfDoneLoading();

    // mock something taking time to load
    setTimeout(() => {
      // when done loading, set loading state to false
      setLoading(false);
    }, 1000);
  }, []);
```

loading is 'captured' as `true` by the closure `testIfDoneLoading()`.

And when you do

```js
useEffect(() => {
    // after loading is false and if we've got a queued function, call the queued function
    if (!loading && queuedFunction.current) {
      // testIfDoneLoading(); // if called directly, this works with the latest state update of `loading` to false
      queuedFunction.current(); // but if called from the queuedFunction, the state change is not registered and `loading` is still true
      queuedFunction.current = undefined;
    }
  }, [loading]);
```

loading is 'captured' as **false** by the closure `testIfDoneLoading()`.

Comment: This makes sense. Is there a way to define or execute on my `queuedFunction` so that it takes the current state of `loading` rather than the state of `loading` at the time of adding it to `queuedFunction`?

Comment: Yes you can pass loading via parameter, the function will use it instead of the loading from the closure state.

code example => [here](https://stackblitz.com/edit/stackblitz-starters-hl4sve?file=src%2FApp.tsx)